# Accordion Image Viewer... Swipe navigation on mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, accordion, swipe

I have an accordion image viewer visible here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gvp8kkeh/1/

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="accordian">
    <ul>
        <li class="item active">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
         <li class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://ih0.redbubble.net/image.7643638.3643/flat,550x550,075,f.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.accordian {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
.accordian ul {width: 200%;}
.accordian li {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 4%;
float: left;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.accordian .active {width: 32%;}
.accordian li img {
display: block;
width: 60vw;
height: auto;
}
```

and the JS:

```
var items = $('.accordian .item');
items.on('mouseover', function (event) {
    items.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

I would like to be able to have the user swipe left and right to navigate through the photos on mobile devices.

Can anyone offer some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery mobile for that. And then you can use something like:

```
$( ".accordian" ).on( "swipeleft", function(event){
items.each(function (event) {
if($(this).hasClass('active))
{
var index = $(this).index();
items.removeClass('active');
items.eq(index-1).addClass('active');
}
});
});
$( ".accordian" ).on( "swiperight", function(event){
items.each(function (event) {
if($(this).hasClass('active))
{
var index = $(this).index();
items.removeClass('active');
items.eq(index+1).addClass('active');
}
});
});
```

Let me know still in case you face any issue.

Comment: Thank you! I guess what I want to figure out is how to make the swipe left and right move to the subsequent <li> by adding the class "active" Should I give each <li> it's own identity in sequence? I'm not exactly sure how to go about this.

Comment: you are the man! Thank you... however it doen't work for me... I am geting a loading message on my page also an erorr message EOF  on the if($(this).hasClass('active))

Comment: It should be $(this).hasClass('active') :) There was ' missing .. typo mistake...

Also, have you included jquery mobile as that is mandatory for swipeleft and swiperight event

Comment: yes I included the min.js. I belive the Jquery Mobile is causing the loading message on the page.no need for the css right?

Comment: Can you please update the same in the fiddle and share please. I will check as if what is causing the issue now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gvp8kkeh/2/  You can also see it at http://interzonestudio.com/tca/build  Navigate to Select Projects > Baby G JP

Comment: I have updated the fiddle and is working fine. The issue was only
if($(this).hasClass('active))
I have changed it to
if($(this).hasClass('active'))

Comment: I removed the Loading message with this: .ui-loader display: none !important;

Comment: Not yet, It must be something I am doing wrong... I really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you still getting the same error .... If yes, have you added the missing single inverted comma on both places?

Comment: No I adjusted that... No errors now, it just doesnt seem to work

Comment: How do you test with jsfiddle on mobile... I can't get the jsfiddle it to work on my iphone either